# ffmpeg wave audio and avi video format merge

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, video-capture

when i used in cmd for merge that it merge successfully ,here is sample code,

ffmpeg -i "D:\Developments\Video Capture\My video capture\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\Video\uuu.wav" -i "D:\Developments\Video Capture\My video capture\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\Video\1.avi" -acodec copy -vcodec copy "D:\Developments\Video Capture\My video capture\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\Video\output.avi"

but here is sample code i used in c# application form,

```
   string Path_FFMPEG = Application.StartupPath + "\\ffmpeg.exe";
        string Wavefile = Application.StartupPath + "\\Video\\uuu.wav";
        string video1 = Application.StartupPath + "\\Video\\1.avi";
        string file = Application.StartupPath + "\\Video\\text.txt";
        string strResult = Application.StartupPath + "\\Video\\output.avi";
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        try
        {

            proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path_FFMPEG;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("ffmpeg -i {0} -i {1} -acodec copy -vcodec copy {2}", Wavefile, video1, strResult); 
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

            proc.Start();

            string StdOutVideo = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string StdErrVideo = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();
        }
```

here is outpu error....

FFmpeg version SVN-r23607, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 15 2010 04:09:35 with gcc 4.4.2
  configuration: --target-os=mingw32 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libfaad --enable-pthreads --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libxvid --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libx264 --extra-libs='-lx264 -lpthread' --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-librtmp --extra-libs='-lrtmp -lpolarssl -lws2_32 -lwinmm' --arch=x86 --cross-prefix=i686-mingw32- --cc='ccache i686-mingw32-gcc' --enable-memalign-hack
  libavutil     50.19. 0 / 50.19. 0
  libavcodec    52.76. 0 / 52.76. 0
  libavformat   52.68. 0 / 52.68. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.20. 0 /  1.20. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
**Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'**

please help me to fix this problem..

Comment: `SVN-r23607` is ancient and unsupported. Why are you using such an old version? You're missing 6 years of development, bug fixes, features, and security fixes.

Answer (score 1):

You are already calling ffmpeg via `proc.StartInfo.FileName`

so change to

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-i {0} -i {1} -acodec copy -vcodec copy {2}", Wavefile, video1, strResult);
```

Comment: I have changed it according to you mentioned but again have another error when changed it all the directory are correct.                                         FFmpeg version SVN-r23607, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  
  libavutil     50.19. 0 / 50.19. 0
  libavcodec    52.76. 0 / 52.76. 0
  libavformat   52.68. 0 / 52.68. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.20. 0 /  1.20. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
D:\Developments\Video: No such file or directory .

Comment: You need to change either your startup path or the path reference in the strings so that the resulting path is `D:\Developments\Video Capture\My video capture\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\Video\`

Comment: I use this code for delay of my audio and video file .ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\aa\Desktop\video\sfdf.avi" -itsoffset 0.150 -i "C:\Users\aa\Desktop\video\sfdf.wav" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 0:0 -map 1:1 "C:\Users\aa\Desktop\video\out.avi" .when i run it show to this error message (Could not find input stream #1.1) how to fix this error.

Comment: It should be `-map 1:0` instead of `-map 1:1`

Comment: I trying to capture audio and video in the same time and merge in single avi file. I recorded audio and the video file but after merge these two file there was a delay that merge file. Audio happens before video. how to fix this. Input #1, wav, from 'C:\Users\aa\Desktop\video\asd.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:05.50, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #1.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
Output #0, avi, to 'C:\Users\aa\Desktop\video\out.avi':  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf52.68.0

    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, 705 kb/s

Comment: Increase value of itsoffset.

Comment: how to start video and audio capture on same time in c#. audio start quickly and video getting late to start.

Comment: I can merge wav into one file.I need to know how to add additional 5 seconds silence length end of the wav file using ffmpeg without merging 5 seconds silent wav file. I just try some codes, ffmpeg -i input1.wav -i silent1.wav -i input2.wav -i silent2.wav ....

Comment: is it possible to get output after merging in "mp4" format ?